# Updating Related Data for Existing Record EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have two tables in a SQL database that look a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Devices
( [Id]      INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL
 ,[Name]    VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL
,CONSTRAINT PK_Device_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Datalogs
( [Id]          INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL
 ,[Device_Id]   INT                 NOT NULL
 ,[Recorded]    DATETIME2(0)        NOT NULL
 ,[Value]       DECIMAL(5,2)            NULL
,CONSTRAINT PK_Datalog_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Id)
,CONSTRAINT FK_Datalog_Device_Id FOREIGN KEY ([Device_Id]) REFERENCES Devices([Id]))
)
```

The data in these tables is put there by a C# project which reads from an API source. I get the data and put it into a C# class called Device, which contains a property declared as follows:

```
[Table("dbo.Devices")]
public partial class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
        Datalogs = new HashSet<Datalog>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Datalog> Datalogs { get; set; }
}
```

when the C# class `Device` has a populated Datalog collection, I write it to the database using this code:

```
public static bool Write_to_DB(Device device)
{
    using (var context = new Factory_Sensors())
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        context.Devices.AddOrUpdate(device);               
        context.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
[.... Excluded Irrelevant Code ....]
    }
}
```

When this code runs for a never-before-recorded Device, it updates the Device and the concomitant Datalogs, but when there is a new datalog collection (e.g. on a new day) on an existing Device, the new datalogs are not added to the database.

I can force the code to update the datalogs by writing something like this immediately after the device based AddOrUpdate:

```
foreach (var log in device.Datalogs)
{
    context.Datalogs.AddOrUpdate(log);
}
```

But not only does this seem to take a lot longer than the original write, it just feels nastily Row By Agonising Row...

Is there a correct way to make sure that new rows of related data are updated even when the Device already exists, or do I have to specify for every record like this?

I have had a look and there does not seem to be a collection based `AddOrUpdate()` equivalent, so I wondered if there was a way to force the code to recognise that the related data is new, even when the Device already exists?

Target Framework .NET 4.8
Entity Framework 6 (I think - 6 is the lowest number it could be)
SQL Server Version 14.0.6

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code, but a *lot* of useless and buggy code. `SaveChanges` persists all pending changes in all tracked objects in a single internal transaction. You don't need an explicit external transaction (that's a major bug actually). You should only call `SaveChanges` once at the very end of your method/unit-of-work to persist the changes. You shouldn't call `AddOrUpdate` or any other state altering method with objects loaded from the DbContext. Those are *already* tracked. These methods are already needed with detached objects

Comment: `it just feels nastily Row By Agonising Row...` yes, and that's a bug in the code you posted. You didn't post the code that actually makes changes though.

Comment: This sounds bad and I'm already a bit confused. Bother. OK... so... Damn.
What is a key word I need to Google to start putting this right?

Comment: `docs`. Start from the EF Core documentation and tutorials. The code you posted came from some bad forum or blog article, perhaps something claiming "best practices" to justify this. I suspect you found some "generic repository" article that put a low-level single-entity repository over what is already a multi-entity repository and unit-of-work (DbContext).

Comment: You can find some *very* good EF Core courses at Pluralsight. These are created by the best known authors, eg the courses by Julie Lerman. The various "free" sites copy those courses but always add bugs like "generic repositories". There's a free 10 day trial but you can get an extended trial period through Microsoft's free [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/). In the past the extended trial ranged between 3 and 6 months.

Comment: In the [Save Data section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/) of the EF Core docs, the [Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) pages shows just how easy it is to add a blog object with posts in [Adding a Graph of New Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-graph-of-new-entities). A single call to `context.Blogs.Add(blog);` will also insert the new Post objects. When you call `Add(blog)` EF will treat both `blog` and any related objects as New.

Comment: The [Adding a Related Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-related-entity) shows that all you need to do to add new posts is load the Blog object and then `Add` the Posts to its `Posts`, property, just like any list. You can also use `List<>.AddRange`

Comment: so basically, I get the existing device from the dbcontext, add the datalogs collection(s) to that and then save changes.... instead of making new devices each time? I think I can find those bits in the documentation to start going.

Comment: sorry - previous comment added before I saw you latest ones.

Comment: Finally [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) covers the case where you get a graph of objects from some other system, eg an API, and have to determine which are new, which are updates etc. When an entity has an autogenerated key , a missing or zero ID means it's a new entity while non-zero means it's an update of an existing entity. The artilce explains how to override this, and even what to do when you have a mix of new and updated objects

Comment: Try with a simple example first. A simple Console application with just a few types, and check the various scenarios. Or create a Unit Test library with one test for each case. Trying to understand how EF works when you already have a large and complicated application makes things a lot harder.